# Calling object variable in method/ function

Tags: php, object

How can I calling a variable that holding object in the method? Any suggestion and help will be very much appreciated.

Here is the example to further my explanation,

This is my class script named shirt.php

```
<?php 
    class shirt {
        //some function and code here
        public getSize() {
            return $this->size;
        }
    }
?>
```

Here is my script that call the shirt.php which named shirt.func.php

```
<?php
    require_once 'shirt.php';

    $shirt = new Shirt();

    function getShirtSize() {
        return $shirt->getSize();
    }
?>
```

The problem is I can't use the variable **$shirt** in the function but if I use it outside the function it works perfectly. I got a way to solve it which is create a method that return the initiation of that object.

This is my way:

```
<?php
    require_once 'foo.php';

    function init() {
        return $shirt = new Shirt();
    }

    function getShirtSize() {
        return init()->getSize();
    }
?>
```

Is there any others effective ways to do so? Thanks for any expertise advise.

Comment: What you're doing is strange. If you really want that, you can define `$shirt` outside and then use `global $shirt;` inside any function you wish to use `$shirt` (or pass it as a param `function getShirtSize($shirt)`. I don't understand why you're not just doing `$shirt = new Shirt(); $shirt_size = $shirt-> getSize();`

Comment: The magic word is `global` !

Comment: This is what function [arguments](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php) are for.

Comment: @adeneo No. Just no. `global` is evil, there is nothing that `global` can solve that cannot be much better solved with injection via arguments.

Comment: What is the purpose of the two asterisk ** ?

Comment: @DaveRandom - Actually, sometimes global is useful, but most of the time it's useless, and most implentations you see around in different code is just lazyness by the developer.

Comment: The reason that why I am not doing $shirt = new Shirt(); $shirt_size = $shirt-> getSize(); is because I want to reuse this function.

Comment: @adeneo The only time `global` is useful *and the best option* is when someone somewhere made a catastrophically bad design decision a long time ago.

Comment: @DaveRandom - I agree, like in most CMS solutions, like Wordpress, where global is used everywhere ?

Comment: @adeneo Indeed, you hit the nail on the head there, general rule of thumb is that if Wordpress does it, you shouldn't do it :-P

Comment: @DaveRandom - I agree! I learnt PHP, javascript and many other languages a long time ago, and the common rule was to always avoid globals, but these days a lot of clients wants WP plugins, widgets and other crap, and the globals, [yoda conditions](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/07/new-programming-jargon.html), and other strangeness in WP is enough to drive anyone crazy at first. Then you sort of get used to it, and it's kinda useful, sometimes.

Comment: got any others suggestion?

Comment: Using `global` is a sign of corrupt design.

Answer (score 0):

```
require_once 'shirt.php';

$shirt = new shirt();

function getShirtSize($_shirt) {
    return $_shirt->getSize();
}

getShirtSize($shirt) // pass the $shirt to the function
```

**EDIT:**

or the (not so) great global:

```
require_once 'shirt.php';

$shirt = new shirt();

function getShirtSize() {
    global $shirt;
    return $shirt->getSize();
}

getShirtSize();
```

Comment: if i want call this method from other script, this will be problem. Got any others suggestion?

Comment: @overshadow - Sure, use global

Answer (score 0):

Methods and functions have their own scope. They only know about objects and scalars, you explicitly provide them with. Thus you have to pass in the object into the function.

```
require_once 'shirt.php';

$myCurrentShirt = new Shirt();

function getShirtSize($shirt) {
    return $shirt->getSize();
}
```

will do it. See the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php) for mor information about the usage of functions.